# How to alter iFrames when third parties request the SRC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, iframe

Edited for clarity: I want to edit an element in my iFrame(s) when a different origin tries to connect.

What I've tried so far:

On pages (the page which will third parties will get my widgets from)
I've added this:

```
function myFunction() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
        var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H2") 
        [0];
        elmnt.style.display = "none";
    }
```

And the code the third parties use will be this:

```
<div style="width:80%;">
<iframe id="myFrame" border="0" frameborder="0" 
src="https://example.com"  
frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" style="min-height:1000px;min-width:500px"> 
</iframe>
</div>
```

As I thought, this does not work. I'm pretty sure as the iFrames are in fact my content, I should be able to modify them based on if they're connected to, right?

My example above is just for testing purposes, trying to remove the H2.

I'm open to any frontend approach, or anything server side with C#.

If anyone could help it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When your widget is embedded on another domain  the *same origin policy* blocks access to it's content from main page

Comment: I don't want to block though, I want to edit an element when a different origin tries to connect.

Comment: Could set up user options and pass them though url query string and modify server side based on those params

Comment: That is not a bad idea. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @charlietfl for the suggestion. I've got it working in C# using parameters.

Frontend:

```
<h2 id="h2IFrame" runat="server">Hello</h2>
```

Server-side in C#

```
var activepage = Request.RawUrl;
        if (activepage.Contains("?noh2"))
    {
        h2IFrame.Visible = false;
    }
    else
        h2IFrame.Visible = true;
```

Using an iFrame like so:

```
<div style="width:80%;">
<iframe id="myFrame" border="0" frameborder="0" 
src="https://example.com?noh2"  
frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" style="min-height:1000px;min-width:500px"> 
</iframe>
</div>
```